# How to separate Boolean expressions on operators (JAVA)?

Tags: java

How to separate Boolean expressions on operators?
I have expressions as the following String:

```
String expression = “((468551X68X304.NAOK == \"2\") and (468551X68X305.NAOK > \"2\") and (468551X68X308.NAOK != \"2000\" or 468551X68X308.NAOK > \"2000\")) “;
```

I want to get all the variables in an array, for example:

```
a[0] = “468551X68X304.NAOK”;
a[1] = “468551X68X305.NAOK”;
a[2] = “468551X68X308.NAOK”;
a[3] = “468551X68X308.NAOK”;
```

May someone give me an idea to solve it?

Thanks,

Comment: You aren't going to get an abundance of help here if you don't at least demonstrate that you have tried something.

Comment: What I need is to know some ideas to solve It. Maybe there are some library that get the operators of an expression. I tried with JEXL but it only operate the expression but do not get the operators of it.

Comment: Yes. You have already stated this in the question. However, that's not how this site works. Do some research on the internet, write some code, and come to us when you have a specific problem with said code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using a regular expression.

The following regex matches the variables that are formatted like the variables in your boolean expressions:

```
\d+X\d+X\d+\.NAOK
```

where every `\d+` matches one or more digits.

To extract the variables using this regex, you can use [`java.util.regex.Pattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and [`java.util.regex.Matcher`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) like this:

```
String booleanExpression = "((468551X68X304.NAOK == \"2\") and (468551X68X305.NAOK > \"2\") and (468551X68X308.NAOK != \"2000\" or 468551X68X308.NAOK > \"2000\")) ";
String regex = "\\d+X\\d+X\\d+\\.NAOK"; // Note that backslash pairs don't denote two backslashes here. Because we're representing the regex as a string literal, we have to use escape sequences to represent the backslashes in the regex

Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(booleanExpression);
ArrayList<String> variables = new ArrayList<>();
while(m.find()) // Match a NEW variable (one that wasn't matched in previous iterations
    variables.add(m.group()); // Add the matched variable to the ArrayList
```